# Bios loading procedure

Tags: authentication, boot, bios, spi, uefi

I need some explaination about the bios load/execution procedure. I need to authenticate the bios executed by the CPU. My idea is to perform the HMAC-SHA1 of the MISO data stream ( the datas from the SPI BIOS Flash to the CPU ).

The problem is that I'm not sure that the MISO data stream is always the same. I did some tries and I get always a different data stream from the previous one. The first part of the stream is always the same, after a while ( I don't have the equipment to dump the whole communication and get the moment when it happens ) the stream is different. I'm not sure but I suspect it is different because I can sniff few bytes of the stream when a counter reaches a specified value and I get different sniffed values. I think the sniffing procedure is correct, but I can't be sure ( The sniffing is performed by a FPGA between CPU and SPI BIOS FLASH and I wrote the VHDL ).

I've noted too that the CPU reads at least 2 times the reset vector ( 0hFFFFF0 ) during the execution of the bios.

Is it possible that the CPU performs different steps at the every power on ? In you opinion is it possible to authenticate the data stream ? What I need is to be sure that the executed bios is a valid bios ( my bios ).

I apoligize if the question is a mess, but my knowledge about the bios and boot procedure are poor.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the system usually resets several times after power-on and BIOS takes different execution paths. Also, the SPI controller may read the flash part in chunks and cache those, so what you see is read from flash is not necessarily what's executed by the CPU. Unfortunately your method is not going to be reliable and there is an industry standard method for doing this, it is called Measured Boot and it involves TPM. Please Google it to get an idea and see if it works for what you need.

Comment: I've read something about TPM, but the problem is it's an option that I can't use. I've read some docs about UEFI processing boot and I get am interesting thing. The first thing the UEFI bios perform is the SEC phase. The SEC phase initialize the CPU and perform an integrity check of the bios. In your opinion, if I find a way to authenticate that part, is it safe to consider that the root of trust of my system ?

Comment: I do not think the SEC code checks integrity of the whole BIOS because it would need to have knowledge of the Firmware Volume (FV) layout and access to cryptographic functions - these may be available in PEI phase, but not SEC. If you want to consider SEC your root of trust then it needs to establish a chain of trust - e.g. at least authenticate the Boot Block, where PEI code usually is, then make sure the verified PEI code authenticates the DXE phase code, etc. to make sure all executable components are authentic.

Comment: You also need to make sure that FVs you authenticate do not have any legitimately changing data, only executable code. There may also be components outside the BIOS FVs, e.g. Option ROMs, which should normally be signed. If you can authenticate all code executed during BIOS POST, as a chain or as a whole, then you can call it trusted.